# No notification triggered on Bot FB Messenger mobile device

Tags: c#, push-notification, botframework, facebook-messenger-bot

When I use Conversations.SendToConversationAsync, the message arrives well on FB messenger but it not there no notification.
How I can make to triggers notification on mobile device for FB messenger?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure Messenger app has notification permissions. On Android, go to Settings -> Apps -> Messenger -> Notifications and make sure that Block All is not checked.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to the activity:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
...
      activity.ChannelData = JObject.FromObject(
      new
      {
          notification_type = "REGULAR"
      });
```